# Popen copying file from other server to my desktop

Tags: python

I'm trying to create simply python script that will auto copy a file from other server to my desktop and I want my script to handle the password without interactive to user. Here's my incomplete program

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("cmd", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate("cd ../../\n" "pscp root@at1:/tmp/summary.txt C:\Arista\Temporary\summary.csv".encode())
print (stdout)
```

This is the actual outcome I wanted to happen.

```
C:\Users\atanacic>pscp root@at1:/tmp/summary.txt C:\Arista\Temporary\summary.csv

root@10.60.20.31's password:

summary.csv               | 44 kB |  44.8 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%

C:\Users\atanacic>
```

Comment: Why not just use a certificate based login rather than keeping the (apparently root) password around in plain text? Other than that, assuming this is _pscp_ from PuTTY, there's a [command line option (`-pw`)](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp) for password...

Comment: Hi Dan, Can you give me an example how it works. Sorry im just a beginner with this python. This script is tend to run every 5 mns.

Comment: @ChristoperAtanacio I haven't read [this](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-pubkey) thoroughly but it's from an pscp guide so I guess it'll apply here.

Comment: @ChristoperAtanacio Nothing to do with Python. As jDo says, and [much more info is on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+public+key+authentication). Regarding the second, just run pscp with that parameter set as the documentation says... like `"pscp -pw 1234 root@at1:/tmp/summary.txt C:\Arista\Temporary\summary.csv"`. The point is to avoid the program reading anything from stdin, it's an unnecessary complication.